# org-mode how to export raw text no formatting?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, text, utf-8

Any quick way to export an org-mode document into a text file with no formatting and no org markup characters?

I am aware of `C-c C-e` `[t] Export to Plain Text` unfortunatly those options add formatting to the document

```
Header 1
═══════════════════════════════════

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do 
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 



Header2
────────────────────────────────────────

  ┌────
  │ code block
  └────
```

The format I'm looking for is:

```
Header 1

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do 
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

Header 2

code block
```

Comment: What do you want to export exactly? org-mode documents are saved as raw text, if you open them up in another editor that's exactly what you'll see. In emacs, `M-x text-mode` or even `M-x fundamental-mode` will remove all syntax-highlighting and show you the raw text.

Comment: I want to export all the text without any of the org-mode formatting characters.

Comment: I usually put the text in #+BEGIN_EXAMPLE and #+END_EXAMPLE block for no org-mode interference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [pandoc](http://pandoc.org), e.g. with [ox-pandoc](https://github.com/kawabata/ox-pandoc).  The command line would be like this:

```
pandoc -t plain -o outfile.txt YOUR_ORG_FILE.org
```

The output is:

```
HEADER 1


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.


Header 2

    code block
```